# Noun+noun in the predicate

Tags: nouns

This is the example of ‘nothing’ in the Cambridge dictionary.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/nothing

> The score is Yankees three, Red Sox nothing.

What is the kind of function of ‘Yankees’ and ‘Red Sox’?

Comment: First of all, you say this is an example of *nothing* -- then you list items. Second, the sentence 'the score is Yankees is three' makes no sense, because that makes Yankees, three, and score the same thing. The original sentence is basically a list of the teams and their runs. "The score is: Yankees - three, Red Sox - nothing."

Comment: I listed the full items...

Comment: It's sports jargon.  The Yankees have three points, and the Red Sox have nothing.

Comment: Ok, you meant an example that uses the word 'nothing' -- I thought you meant an example of nothing itself, which would be weird. My apologies.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan I know, I mean what part of a sentence ‘Yankees’ is. Subject, object, adjunct.

Comment: Everything after *is* is a list item -- they are all nouns. Yankees and Red Sox are teams, so they are nouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an idiomatic way of expressing the score of a sporting event. If you imagine an actual scoreboard next to the field, it might display something like this:

```
Yankees - 3
Red Sox - 0
```

If you just read off the words and numbers on the board, it would sound like "Yankees three, Red Sox zero". This is a very common way to recite the score of a match. This example is doing essentially that, except that it's substituting the word "nothing" (meaning "no home runs" or "no points scored") for the number zero.